# Selenium crashes upon starting in Java

Tags: java, spring-boot, selenium-webdriver

I have created a spring boot app (v3.2.4). I have Chrome installed and installed relevant chrome driver (v 123.0.6312.86 (Official Build) (64-bit)). I have got the selenium from maven (v4.19.1).

I was getting start to build a web scraper. I have literally created a bean of ChromeDriver, set the property to the chromeDriver

```
@Configuration
public class Config {

    @PostConstruct
    public void setUp() {
        System.getProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Users\\Admin\\Desktop\\WebScraper\\chromedriver-win64\\chromedriver-win64");
    }

    @Bean
    public ChromeDriver chromeDriver () {
        return new ChromeDriver();
    }

}
```

And then to test the configuration set, I've set up a simple service file

```
@Service
public class ScrapeService {

    private final ChromeDriver chromeDriver;

    public ScrapeService(ChromeDriver chromeDriver) {
        this.chromeDriver = chromeDriver;
    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void scrape() {
        System.out.println("Starting Scrape!. Is chromeDriver not null:  " + chromeDriver != null);
    }
}
```

But I get the following. Not sure as to why I'm getting the error. Looking at the stacktrace, it seems like some network config? E.g. could it be my firewall blocking the request being sent from the driver?:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver]: Factory method 'chromeDriver' threw exception with message: Could not start a new session. Unable to parse remote response: invalid websocket request url path 
Host info: host: 'DESKTOP-8TH8AML', ip: '192.168.1.229'
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:177) ~[spring-beans-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:644) ~[spring-beans-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    ... 33 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Could not start a new session. Unable to parse remote response: invalid websocket request url path 
Host info: host: 'DESKTOP-8TH8AML', ip: '192.168.1.229'
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:126) ~[selenium-remote-driver-4.14.1.jar:na]
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:96) ~[selenium-remote-driver-4.14.1.jar:na]
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:68) ~[selenium-remote-driver-4.14.1.jar:na]
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:163) ~[selenium-remote-driver-4.14.1.jar:na]
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.invokeExecute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:200) ~[selenium-remote-driver-4.14.1.jar:na]
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:175) ~[selenium-remote-driver-4.14.1.jar:na]
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:602) ~[selenium-remote-driver-4.14.1.jar:na]
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:236) ~[selenium-remote-driver-4.14.1.jar:na]
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:163) ~[selenium-remote-driver-4.14.1.jar:na]
    at org.openqa.selenium.chromium.ChromiumDriver.<init>(ChromiumDriver.java:108) ~[selenium-chromium-driver-4.14.1.jar:na]
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:88) ~[selenium-chrome-driver-4.14.1.jar:na]
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:83) ~[selenium-chrome-driver-4.14.1.jar:na]
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:51) ~[selenium-chrome-driver-4.14.1.jar:na]
    at com.example.demo.Config.chromeDriver(Config.java:18) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.example.demo.Config$$SpringCGLIB$$0.CGLIB$chromeDriver$1(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.example.demo.Config$$SpringCGLIB$$FastClass$$1.invoke(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:258) ~[spring-core-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:331) ~[spring-context-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at com.example.demo.Config$$SpringCGLIB$$0.chromeDriver(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:103) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:580) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:140) ~[spring-beans-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    ... 34 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.json.JsonException: Unable to parse: invalid websocket request url path
    at org.openqa.selenium.json.Json.toType(Json.java:169) ~[selenium-json-4.14.1.jar:na]
    at org.openqa.selenium.json.Json.toType(Json.java:152) ~[selenium-json-4.14.1.jar:na]
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:122) ~[selenium-remote-driver-4.14.1.jar:na]
    ... 55 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.json.JsonException: Unable to determine type from: i. Last 1 characters read: i
Build info: version: '4.14.1', revision: '03f8ede370'
System info: os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '21.0.2'
Driver info: driver.version: ChromeDriver
    at org.openqa.selenium.json.JsonInput.peek(JsonInput.java:164) ~[selenium-json-4.14.1.jar:na]
    at org.openqa.selenium.json.JsonTypeCoercer.lambda$buildCoercer$6(JsonTypeCoercer.java:170) ~[selenium-json-4.14.1.jar:na]
    at org.openqa.selenium.json.JsonTypeCoercer.coerce(JsonTypeCoercer.java:149) ~[selenium-json-4.14.1.jar:na]
    at org.openqa.selenium.json.Json.toType(Json.java:206) ~[selenium-json-4.14.1.jar:na]
    at org.openqa.selenium.json.Json.toType(Json.java:167) ~[selenium-json-4.14.1.jar:na]
```